# Why do I get this NullPointerException in my DAO?

Tags: hibernate, maven, struts2

I'm working on a project where I already use Struts 2 with Maven 3 and Tiles. Now I would like to use a database but I've a problem with Hibernate and Struts 2.

I followed this tutorial : http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-hibernate-integration-with-full-hibernate-plugin/ and I have this error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> ```
> com.facilityrh.dao.FormationDAOImpl.list(FormationDAOImpl.java:23)
> com.facilityrh.action.FormationAction.list(FormationAction.java:29)
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
> org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
> org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
> org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
> ```

I changed Customer by Formation and in the database I just created a table with an id and a name.

Here is a link with the differents files used (on a ftp, else the post would be too long) :
http://dev.aurelienpraga.com/stackoverflow/rh-client/

I made an other tutorial with annotations Hibernate and without Maven, it works fine but when I try to use Maven, I have the same error.

Where is the problem ?

And also what is the difference between use .hbm.xml files to describe the tables and annotation system?

Comment: The link for the tutorial with Hibernate and annotations : http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-hibernate-integration-1.html

Comment: Could you at *least* tell us what's null?

Comment: The line : return session.createQuery("from formation").list(); FormationDAOImpl.java

Comment: So, what's null in that line?

Comment: I think the problem come to the configuration because if i try to delete or update a row, the error is the same.